# How to make unique() not to distinguish numeric from integer?

Tags: r

It seems that `unique()` by default distinguishes objects of all modes. For example,

```
> unique(list(1,1L))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1
```

Is there a way to make `unique()` not to distinguish `numeric` from `integer` and no other changes so that it behaves like

```
> unique(list(1,1L,"a"))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "a"
```

where `1L` is coerced to `numeric`.

Is there existing function that does this already or I have to write a new one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that there's an existing packaged-up  function that does this, mostly because it's so simple to roll one for yourself:

```
myUnique <- function(ll) {
    deInt <- function(X) if(is.integer(X)) as.numeric(X) else X
    unique(rapply(ll, deInt, how="replace"))
}
myUnique(l)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
```

Comment: Thanks! the use of `ifelse()` makes the function only works with single-valued vectors :) maybe using `if...else...` is better?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're mucking with a `list` . Here's some examples when not using a list:

```
Rgames> foo<-c(1.0,1L)
Rgames> unique(foo)
[1] 1
Rgames> class(foo)
[1] "numeric"
Rgames> foo<-c(1.0,1L,'a')
Rgames> unique(foo)
[1] "1" "a"
```

`R` automatically coerces all elements of a vector to the first class which can accommodate all the elements.    You will have to decide for yourself whether you want to distinguish `character(1)` from `1L` , for example. Josh's nice example works for numbers, i.e. `numeric` and `integer`, but not for character-class "numbers" .